# How to Segue to a specific view controller depending on the Segue identity, from a Collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, collectionview

Currently developing a small ios app in swift, I have populated a collection view cell with data from a .plist, each cell has a title and button, what i'm wanting is to segue to multiple view controllers in the storyboard depending on the segue identity once the button is pressed. For example if the segue has the id set as food, i want it to navigate to the view called food?

or if it is easier for the segue to pull the title from the cell then navigate to the view with the same title as the cell?

ill try and explain in code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{
  if segue.identifier == "food"
  {
    //then navigate to the view controller called food
  }
  else if segue.identifier == "drink"{
  {
    //navigate to the view called drink
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want the code of transitioning between the view controllers?

Comment: Do drink and food have their own individual views?

Answer (score 1):

If food, drink or any other items have their own unique view in storyboard this is achievable.

You can assign a string to each button in UICollectionView and check which item in the collection was tapped and do a `performSegueWithIdentifier:` with button string.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("toComments", sender: self)
```

Then `prepareForSegue:` method to pass data. Do another if for **drink**.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toFood" {
        let ExchangeViewData = segue.destinationViewController as! FoodViewController
        ExchangeViewData.foodMenuToShow = foodMenuID //This can be anything that you get your food items.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thankyou. I am getting an error on the = foodMenuID         I achieved what I am wanting in obj-c with the follwoing but I am new to swift: `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Offers"]) { OffersViewController *offerView = segue.destinationViewController; [offerView setTitle:@"Offers"]; `

Comment: Well, `foodMenuID` it's a variable data you're sending to second view make sure you have it in first view. Like I say, it can be different, it all depend on what type of data your passing to second view, also second view variable should match this as well.

Comment: I managed to find time to correct the code but it doesn't work as expected, it only navigates to the initial VC successfully passing data to that VC but does so irrelevant to which cell I select.  I have 3 view controllers and 3 cells, the segue for each VC is connected to the VC containing the collectionview.

Comment: You should have the data ready in the view your going to, either getting it from server or is already in a variable and do a `switch` statement on the data that was pass from initial VC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are asking for. A segue identifier is what determines which view controller gets invoked by the segue. If you want to go to a different view controller, invoke a segue with a different identifier. By the time you get to `prepareForSegue` it's too late. The segue to a specific view controller is already in progress.

You should explain what it is you're trying to do and we can help you solve your problem rather than trying to fight the APIs and do something that's neither possible nor appropriate. (Your question is an example of an "[**XY problem**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)".)

Comment: Apologies for my poor explanation, long day in the office. Basically I have a View Controller that contains a collection view, this then contains a cell containing a label and a button. This cell is populated using a .plist containing a dictionary of images and label names. What I want is depending on which button is selected and which label that button has, the app will navigate to the corresponding view.

Comment: This is how I managed it in obj-c:                                                                            if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Offers"]) {
        OffersViewController *offerView = segue.destinationViewController;
        [offerView setTitle:@"Offers"];